# Custom Post Type monthly archive

Tags: php, wordpress, archive, custom-post-type

I have the following code in my functions.php:

```
function add_rewrite_rules($aRules) {
    $aNewRules = array(
        'news/([0-9]{4})/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=news&year=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]',
        'news/([0-9]{4})/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=news&year=$matches[1]',
        'blog/([0-9]{4})/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=blog&year=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]',
        'blog/([0-9]{4})/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=blog&year=$matches[1]'
    );
    $aRules = $aNewRules + $aRules;
    return $aRules;
}

add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', 'add_rewrite_rules');
```

This has made my permalinks work like this:

`/blog`

`/blog/post-name`

`/blog/2014`

I don't understand the code well enough to adapt it to do monthly archives like:

`/blog/2014/01`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
 'blog/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{1,2})/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=blog&year=$matches[1]&monthnum=$matches[2]'
```

to your array.

Comment: It stops going to page not found, but shows all of the posts on every month rather than filtering them

Comment: @CarlaDessi Try now, I edited the answer.

(changed month to monthnum)

Comment: Now every month shoes page not found